# Using a central server with php

Tags: php, lamp, centralized

Let's say I have 3 websites hosted in server a, b and c, they all use some of the same files (library.php, users.php, config...). Right now all website have those files, and if I want to update 1 of the files I have to do it for all websites. Very inefficient.

The question is could I have a central server that hosts those common files and when one of the websites is loaded I get PHP to call library.php, users.php... from the central server?

Comment: Which information you store in this centralized files? I think there is a better way to share this informations.

Comment: there are many classes, methods, configurations files...

Comment: I think its not the best way to share these files. The problem is that all your projects are unreachable without a local copy, when the "centralized server" ist not response due server timeout or something else. Use a CSV, a private repository to share these files  with all your projects and update it when you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You COULD use a central server, or set one of the 3 servers as the shared respository for all files, but that is going to cause unnecessary network overhead and also reintroduce a single point of failure.

A better method would be to implement a set of scripts that would keep the servers in sync.

[Rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) can be used for this, but there are any number of options including using git. (You DO use source code management right?)

[Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) is also a good option.

Also see answers here: [Deploying to multiple servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96405/deploying-to-multiple-servers)

Comment: Lot's of great recommendations. Another option would be to use Composer and run it regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a shared directory on your server and add them to the PHP include path.